# Create rectified GeoTIFF given aux.xml produced from ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I'm trying to create the rectified GeoTIFF image, given a raster TIFF image and aux.xml file generated from ArcGIS. The aux.xml contains information about the mapping from raster TIFF image to the EPSG3857 coord system.

I have tried both `gdal_translate` and `gdalwarp` but these two commands do not seem to translate the image into right coordinate system.

The source.aux.xml and source.tif are placed in the same folder, and I assume gdal_translate should be able to parse it automatically. But I'm new to GDAL so I might be wrong.

The commands that I have tried are:

`gdal_translate -of Gtiff data/source.tif out.tif`

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 data/source.tif output.tif`

I have also tried feeding two GCPs manually in the command line:

`gdal_translate -of Gtiff -gcp 1010.12399710495 3376.53784704463 -12353281.1660675 3792598.78418559 -gcp 1444.89669523737 7462.16039148392 -12353247.9864842 3792353.93607001  data/00180_1901-0009.tif out.tif`

and

`gdal_translate -of Gtiff -gcp 1010.12399710495 3376.53784704463 -12353281.1660675 3792598.78418559 -gcp 1444.89669523737 7462.16039148392 -12353247.9864842 3792353.93607001 -a_srs EPSG:3857  data/00180_1901-0009.tif out.tif`

But they do not work either.

-------------------  Edit on Mar 21  ------------------------

The tif file and aux.xml are available in [this folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1za9Ii4okukfjBhc6MVf_TSlpVF_SLTLF?usp=sharing).

The reason that I think the command failed is because the output tif file is located at the apparently wrong location after loading to QGIS. See the red circle in the picture below.
[image]

using `gdalinfo data/source.tif` command, this is what I got:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: data/00180_1901-0009.tif
       data/00180_1901-0009.tif.ovr
       data/00180_1901-0009.tif.aux.xml
Size is 6510, 7680
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (0.000000000000000,25.600000000000001)
Pixel Size = (0.003333333333333,-0.003333333333333)
GCP Projection = 
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=, Info=
          (1010.12399710495,3376.53784704463) -> (-12353281.1660675,3792598.78418559,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=, Info=
          (1207.41887334734,5677.20283183269) -> (-12353265.7025088,3792473.83559428,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=, Info=
          (6203.78509854017,2201.33101971704) -> (-12352975.1206273,3792673.69571776,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=, Info=
          (3963.31348233061,2646.54943770845) -> (-12353101.9811321,3792639.8853629,0)
GCP[  4]: Id=, Info=
          (3673.3365990744,453.902742157225) -> (-12353119.5453051,3792796.20397223,0)
GCP[  5]: Id=, Info=
          (638.429269914309,141.212823365349) -> (-12353304.6144917,3792789.87682056,0)
GCP[  6]: Id=, Info=
          (3879.98499417461,5502.94280813949) -> (-12353104.6764987,3792482.69360664,0)
GCP[  7]: Id=, Info=
          (6136.20177056523,7162.84261248191) -> (-12352969.2754528,3792380.51010706,0)
GCP[  8]: Id=, Info=
          (4047.38722072111,7187.30468358379) -> (-12353094.2366984,3792374.18295538,0)
GCP[  9]: Id=, Info=
          (1444.89669523737,7462.16039148392) -> (-12353247.9864842,3792353.93607001,0)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=300
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=300
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,  25.6000000) 
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Upper Right (  21.7000000,  25.6000000) 
Lower Right (  21.7000000,   0.0000000) 
Center      (  10.8500000,  12.8000000) 
Band 1 Block=6510x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 3255x3840, 1628x1920, 814x960, 407x480, 204x240
Band 2 Block=6510x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 3255x3840, 1628x1920, 814x960, 407x480, 204x240
Band 3 Block=6510x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 3255x3840, 1628x1920, 814x960, 407x480, 204x240
```

The aux.xml file is attached here:

```
<PAMDataset>
  <Metadata domain="Esri">
    <MDI key="PyramidResamplingType">NEAREST</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <Metadata domain="xml:ESRI" format="xml">
    <GeodataXform xsi:type="typens:PolynomialXform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/2.6.0">
      <PolynomialOrder>1</PolynomialOrder>
      <SpatialReference xsi:type="typens:ProjectedCoordinateSystem">
        <WKT>PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",3857]]</WKT>
        <XOrigin>-20037700</XOrigin>
        <YOrigin>-30241100</YOrigin>
        <XYScale>148923141.92838538</XYScale>
        <ZOrigin>-100000</ZOrigin>
        <ZScale>10000</ZScale>
        <MOrigin>-100000</MOrigin>
        <MScale>10000</MScale>
        <XYTolerance>0.001</XYTolerance>
        <ZTolerance>0.001</ZTolerance>
        <MTolerance>0.001</MTolerance>
        <HighPrecision>true</HighPrecision>
        <WKID>102100</WKID>
        <LatestWKID>3857</LatestWKID>
      </SpatialReference>
      <SourceGCPs xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfDouble">
        <Double>3.3670799903498199</Double>
        <Double>14.344873843184562</Double>
        <Double>4.0247295778244734</Double>
        <Double>6.6759905605576932</Double>
        <Double>20.679283661800582</Double>
        <Double>18.262229934276547</Double>
        <Double>13.211044941102045</Double>
        <Double>16.778168540971819</Double>
        <Double>12.244455330248002</Double>
        <Double>24.086990859475918</Double>
        <Double>2.1280975663810295</Double>
        <Double>25.129290588782169</Double>
        <Double>12.933283313915354</Double>
        <Double>7.2568573062017094</Double>
        <Double>20.454005901884102</Double>
        <Double>1.7238579583936371</Double>
        <Double>13.491290735737039</Double>
        <Double>1.6423177213873714</Double>
        <Double>4.8163223174578889</Double>
        <Double>0.72613202838692814</Double>
      </SourceGCPs>
      <TargetGCPs xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfDouble">
        <Double>-12353281.166067505</Double>
        <Double>3792598.784185593</Double>
        <Double>-12353265.702508822</Double>
        <Double>3792473.8355942797</Double>
        <Double>-12352975.120627346</Double>
        <Double>3792673.6957177576</Double>
        <Double>-12353101.981132057</Double>
        <Double>3792639.885362898</Double>
        <Double>-12353119.545305107</Double>
        <Double>3792796.2039722297</Double>
        <Double>-12353304.614491669</Double>
        <Double>3792789.8768205559</Double>
        <Double>-12353104.676498685</Double>
        <Double>3792482.6936066402</Double>
        <Double>-12352969.275452796</Double>
        <Double>3792380.5101070567</Double>
        <Double>-12353094.236698417</Double>
        <Double>3792374.1829553796</Double>
        <Double>-12353247.986484168</Double>
        <Double>3792353.9360700133</Double>
      </TargetGCPs>
      <Name />
    </GeodataXform>
  </Metadata>
</PAMDataset>
```

Comment: Gdal seems to read the coordinate system and GCPs fine. Your gdalwarp command should do the right thing and create a north-up image without GCPs. What makes you think that there is something wrong?

Comment: Your gdal_translate commands add ground control points into the image by writing them into image metadata with TIFF tags but gdal_translate does not warp the image physically. With GCPs software that knows what to do with them, for example gdalwarp, can warp the image. QGIS and ArcGIS can also warp an image with GCPs on-the-fly and show them correctly on the map.

Comment: @user30184 The map image is located at the wrong location after loading to QGIS. I have edited the question and added a picuture to explain this.

Comment: @user30184 I see. So I should use gdalwarp instead of gdaltranslate. The georeferecing is done in ArcGIS by someone else, and I'd like to view it in QGIS. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, it is all too difficult to make guesses without having access to the image. If you cannot share the image with information where it should be on the map I cannot help more. There is something odd in the data that you show. I had a try with on artificial image and your aux.xml file and the first GCP that gdalinfo shows is `GCP[  0]: Id=, Info= (3.36707999034982,14.3448738431846) -> (-12353281.1660675,3792598.78418559,0)`. You had very different values for the pixel coordinates `(1010.12399710495,3376.53784704463) -> (-12353281.1660675,3792598.78418559,0)` and I do not understand that.

Comment: @user30184, Thanks for looking into this! I guess the weird coordinnates might due to the scale (XYScale or Zscale in aux.xml). I have added a GoogleDrive link in the question above if you are interested in trying it out.

Comment: Your reason for the problem is probably the file 00180_1901-0009.tif itself and GCP issue is a red herring. The tiff file is a GeoTIFF with this georeferencing info `origin (0.00,25.600) pixel size 0.00333,-0.00333)`. The tfw file and aux.xml file contain different georeferencing but QGIS maybe prefers to use the internal data from the GeoTIFF tags. I will have a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for providing the source data. It would have been impossible to resolve this nasty problem without being able to investigate the original TIFF image that is buggy.

The reason for the problem is that the dataset has several sources for the georeferencing and one of them it totally wrong.

1. Internal GeoTIFF tags
2. World file .tfw
3. Extented world file .tfwx
4. The aux.xml file

I do not know ESRI systems well enough to say if tfwx is actually used together with the aux.xml. Anyway the georeferencing that is stored into GeoTIFF tags is wrong and unfortunately that is the one that GDAL and QGIS seem to be using by default.

For finding out the wrong GeoTIFF metadata the file  00180_1901-0009.tif must be alone in the directory without aux.xml because gdalinfo does interpret the aux.xml file when it exists.

```
gdalinfo 00180_1901-0009.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 00180_1901-0009.tif
Size is 6510, 7680
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",
...
Origin = (0.000000000000000,25.600000000000001)
Pixel Size = (0.003333333333333,-0.003333333333333)
```

Data are all wrong: the coordinate system is EPSG:3857, pixel size is 3.3 millimeters, and the image is located very near to Null Island. You can find proper values from the tfw file: pixel size about 6 centimeters and location in the USA.

```
0.0595089510584668191
0.00104184063139343909
0.0010093548050564196
-0.060101796092413777
-12353342.2684314027
3792804.27322709654
```

The GDAL GeoTIFF documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#georeferencing gives this information

> If no georeferencing information is available in the TIFF file itself,
> GDAL will also check for, and use an ESRI world file with the
> extension .tfw, .tifw/.tiffw or .wld, as well as a MapInfo .tab file.
>
> By default, information is fetched in following order (first listed is
> the most prioritary): PAM (Persistent Auxiliary metadata) .aux.xml
> sidecar file, INTERNAL (GeoTIFF keys and tags), TABFILE (.tab),
> WORLDFILE (.tfw, .tifw/.tiffw or .wld).
>
> Starting with GDAL 2.2, the allowed sources and their priority order
> can be changed with the GDAL_GEOREF_SOURCES configuration option (or
> GEOREF_SOURCES open option) whose value is a comma-separated list of
> the following keywords : PAM, INTERNAL, TABFILE, WORLDFILE, NONE.
> First mentioned sources are the most prioritary over the next ones. A
> non mentioned source will be ignored.

By the documentation, because the PAM file exists it should have a priority over GeoTIFF tags. So it seems to have for gdalinfo but not for gdalwarp and not for QGIS either. The latter two are placing the image nearby Null Island.

**EDIT** It appeared that the ordering of the georeference sources did not handle right the kind of mixture that appeared in your data and therefore GDAL was reading both aux.xml and the TIFF tags. That would not have been any problem if they were both correct but in this case the TIFF tags which were used later in the process were wrong. The future GDAL versions will read only the aux.xml file in similar cases.

It is possible to force QGIS to use the aux.xml file with an option in the Add raster file dialogue

[image]

The image opens warped by the GCPs and in correct place

[image]

Gdalwarp and other GDAL utilities can be forced to use PAM with a configuration option

```
gdalwarp 00180_1901-0009.tif warped.tif --config GDAL_GEOREF_SOURCES PAM
```

Comment: This is awsome!! Thanks for the detailed answer. I have marked this as the accepted answer.