# Warping ArcGIS 9.2 georeferenced TIFFs using GDAL warp

Tags: georeferencing, gdalwarp, arcgis-9.2

I have hundreds of very large TIFFs which were georeferenced 15+ years ago using ArcGIS 9.2.  Viewing them in ArcMap 9.2 the images are properly located and sized/warped on the map.  However, they need to be rectified to the final projection.  The GCPs are embedded in the TIF and also in the tif.xml file.
While I can achieve warping to a final rectified image using the Clip tool, it takes a long time for each image.
I've tried using GDAL warp utilities to do this, but am getting empty final images (all black).
eg:

`\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalwarp.exe -overwrite -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.tif out.tif`

`\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalwarp.exe -overwrite --config GDAL_GEOREF_SOURCES PAM -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.tif out.tif`

Here is the output from `\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalinfo.exe IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.tif`:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.tif
       IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.aux
       IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.rrd
       IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.tif.aux.xml
Size is 18565, 18492
GCP Projection =
PROJCRS["Canada_Lambert_Conformal_Conic",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6269]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",40,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",50,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",70,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
GCP[  0]: Id=, Info=
          (16.5886813769484,11.2421187314794) -> (1298609.77217853,2919147.39696529,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=, Info=
          (16.8939942179049,11.7402607351451) -> (1298500.0219128,2919153.17329506,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=, Info=
          (18.8921073940182,10.0052797183835) -> (1298631.40807544,2919617.77480046,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=, Info=
          (21.4572641379127,13.0572806764721) -> (1297892.90562009,2919783.3167529,0)
GCP[  4]: Id=, Info=
          (19.6528779424261,13.8720869249719) -> (1297910.23024105,2919417.7417536,0)
GCP[  5]: Id=, Info=
          (20.6880569996538,12.0845177405408) -> (1298127.44460173,2919739.01694754,0)
GCP[  6]: Id=, Info=
          (21.5855745124354,11.8220205578855) -> (1298091.07382506,2919911.77813673,0)
GCP[  7]: Id=, Info=
          (19.6699549399509,11.5899398962065) -> (1298297.65636365,2919614.6948765,0)
GCP[  8]: Id=, Info=
          (19.2596578670837,14.6946775183915) -> (1297815.43048519,2919292.29625073,0)
GCP[  9]: Id=, Info=
          (18.8790359460127,12.7118694177316) -> (1298182.37712172,2919377.79059004,0)
GCP[ 10]: Id=, Info=
          (17.0335864905755,13.3239667836351) -> (1298226.2344595,2919045.4523473,0)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=255
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=0
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=3 (pixels/cm)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=800.26886
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=800.14081
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,18492.0)
Upper Right (18565.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (18565.0,18492.0)
Center      ( 9282.5, 9246.0)
Band 1 Block=18565x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 4642x4623, 2321x2312, 1161x1156, 581x578, 291x289, 146x145, 73x73, 37x37
```

and the `IQALUIT_1948_A11535_043.tif.aux.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<GeodataXform xsi:type='typens:PolynomialXform' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
              xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:typens='http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/9.2'>
    <PolynomialOrder>1</PolynomialOrder>
    <SpatialReference xsi:type='typens:ProjectedCoordinateSystem'>
        <WKT>PROJCS[&quot;Canada_Lambert_Conformal_Conic&quot;,GEOGCS[&quot;GCS_North_American_1983&quot;,DATUM[&quot;D_North_American_1983&quot;,SPHEROID[&quot;GRS_1980&quot;,6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;,0.0],UNIT[&quot;Degree&quot;,0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[&quot;Lambert_Conformal_Conic&quot;],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Easting&quot;,0.0],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Northing&quot;,0.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Central_Meridian&quot;,-96.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Standard_Parallel_1&quot;,50.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Standard_Parallel_2&quot;,70.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Latitude_Of_Origin&quot;,40.0],UNIT[&quot;Meter&quot;,1.0]]</WKT>
        <XOrigin>-35105400</XOrigin>
        <YOrigin>-29255500</YOrigin>
        <XYScale>128287945.084531</XYScale>
        <ZOrigin>-100000</ZOrigin>
        <ZScale>10000</ZScale>
        <MOrigin>-100000</MOrigin>
        <MScale>10000</MScale>
        <XYTolerance>1.55899293474704E-08</XYTolerance>
        <ZTolerance>0.0002</ZTolerance>
        <MTolerance>0.0002</MTolerance>
        <HighPrecision>true</HighPrecision>
    </SpatialReference>
    <SourceGCPs xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfDouble'>
        <Double>16.5886813769484</Double>
        <Double>11.2421187314794</Double>
        <Double>16.8939942179049</Double>
        <Double>11.7402607351451</Double>
        <Double>18.8921073940182</Double>
        <Double>10.0052797183835</Double>
        <Double>21.4572641379127</Double>
        <Double>13.0572806764721</Double>
        <Double>19.6528779424261</Double>
        <Double>13.8720869249719</Double>
        <Double>20.6880569996538</Double>
        <Double>12.0845177405408</Double>
        <Double>21.5855745124354</Double>
        <Double>11.8220205578855</Double>
        <Double>19.6699549399509</Double>
        <Double>11.5899398962065</Double>
        <Double>19.2596578670837</Double>
        <Double>14.6946775183915</Double>
        <Double>18.8790359460127</Double>
        <Double>12.7118694177316</Double>
        <Double>17.0335864905755</Double>
        <Double>13.3239667836351</Double>
    </SourceGCPs>
    <TargetGCPs xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfDouble'>
        <Double>1298609.77217853</Double>
        <Double>2919147.39696529</Double>
        <Double>1298500.0219128</Double>
        <Double>2919153.17329506</Double>
        <Double>1298631.40807544</Double>
        <Double>2919617.77480046</Double>
        <Double>1297892.90562009</Double>
        <Double>2919783.3167529</Double>
        <Double>1297910.23024105</Double>
        <Double>2919417.7417536</Double>
        <Double>1298127.44460173</Double>
        <Double>2919739.01694754</Double>
        <Double>1298091.07382506</Double>
        <Double>2919911.77813673</Double>
        <Double>1298297.65636365</Double>
        <Double>2919614.6948765</Double>
        <Double>1297815.43048519</Double>
        <Double>2919292.29625073</Double>
        <Double>1298182.37712172</Double>
        <Double>2919377.79059004</Double>
        <Double>1298226.2344595</Double>
        <Double>2919045.4523473</Double>
    </TargetGCPs>
</GeodataXform>
```

I don't understand the units of the ESRI sourceGCPs - why the values are so small. Is it an offset instead of a pixel position, or coordinate?

What is the correct `gdalwarp` command to use to get this to rectify properly? (the same projected CRS as the source can be used for the target.)

(I've already looked at [Create rectified GeoTIFF given aux.xml produced from ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426418/create-rectified-geotiff-given-aux-xml-produced-from-arcgis))

Comment: How does the gdalinfo about out.tif look like?

Comment: Can you share the data? GDAL should be able to convert the small source pixel/line values from the aux.xml file into full pixels but with your dataset the conversion fails for some reason.

Comment: Follow the progress of https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/7484. ESRI has a special alternative for giving the source coordinates, if I understand right it means centimeters or inches from the corner if the original was a paper print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL did not support just that combination of ESRI variant of ground control points, TIFF, and aux.xml file. GDAL developers have verified and fixed the issue  https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/7484. Install the development version of GDAL or build it from the sources and you can warp your images correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a go.